# Composer: The disk hosting /home/user/.composer is full, this may be the cause of the following exception

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I'm deploying a small Symfony 4 application on a shared hosting.
I have SSH access.

When I run composer update, I get an error like this:

```
$ composer update --no-dev
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Generating autoload files
ocramius/package-versions:  Generating version class...
ocramius/package-versions: ...done generating version class
The disk hosting /home/user/.composer is full, this may be the cause of the following exception


[ErrorException]
escapeshellarg() has been disabled for security reasons
```

Same thing happens when performing a diagnose:

```
$ composer diagnose
Checking composer.json: OK
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: The disk hosting /home/user/.composer is full, this may be the cause of the following exception
```

I already cleared the cache, but that didn't change anything:

```
$ composer clearcache
Cache directory does not exist (cache-vcs-dir): 
Clearing cache (cache-repo-dir): /home/user/.composer/cache/repo
Clearing cache (cache-files-dir): /home/user/.composer/cache/files
Clearing cache (cache-dir): /home/user/.composer/cache
All caches cleared.
```

I have a quota of 1GB and for the moment I'm not using 200MB, so there is still some space left. When the error rises, the cache folder is around 89MB.

Does anyone have had this issue or know how to solve this? 
I'm also looking at this with the people of my hosting company (who are really trying their best!)...

Answer (score 0):

I think it's due to a lack of RAM memory, does your hosting gives you the ability to upgrade memory for tests ?

What's your hosting provider ?

Comment: I don't know the amount of RAM available.